# navigationBarHidden false => true brings problems with toplayoutguide on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, autolayout, uinavigationbar

for one ViewController in my navigation stack I'm hiding the navigationBar (`navigationBarHidden = true` in `viewWillAppear:` and `navigationBarHidden = false` in `viewWillDisappear:`).

After that, the topLayoutGuide is moved up by 40 pixels, if I animate a view to toplayoutguide = 0, the view is out of sight.

This only happens on iOS 7 - how can I prevent this?